# Python Breakfast Item Menu issue

Tags: python

I'm new to python so in advance, Please excuse the lack of knowledge that may be present.

I'm **working on** a simple **Breakfast Menu Items list**. of course there are many ways of handling this, I've chosen this way. A "beginners" way.  **Below is the code I'm using.** When it get's to the Toppings section, receives the input. It goes to the print() method and crashes due to "Meal" not being defined. I ran the debugger via Python which helps me understand what is going on. after the input value is received and runs thru the if elif else statement, why won't the value "stay put" long enough to return the whole value of all 3 selections?  Thanks in Advance....

I'm still learning; eventually there will be other statements that'll provide other options, if I choose something outside the options, a function will happen. 
If I choose just 2 or 1 of the options, the output will show. For now, this is giving me an issue. Please Please Please Pleaseeeeeee I need help, fellow student to teachers.

**# ACTUAL CODE BEING USED**

```
print("1. Eggs")
print("2. Pancakes")
print("3. Waffles")
print("4. OatMeal")
MainChoice = int(input("Choose a breakfast item #: "))
if(MainChoice == 1):
    Meal = "Eggs"
    print("You've Choosen eggs")
elif (MainChoice == 2):
    Meal = "Pancakes"
    print("You've Choosen pankcakes")
elif (MainChoice == 3):
    Meal = "Waffles"
    print("You've Choosen waffles")
else:
    print("You've Choosen Oatmeal")

if (MainChoice <= 4):
    print("1. Wheat Toast")
    print("2. Sour Dough")
    print("3. Rye Toast")
    print("4. White Bread")
Bread = int(input("Choose a type of bread: "))
elif (Bread == 1):
    print("You chose " + Meal + "  with wheat toast.")
elif (Bread == 2):
    print("You chose " + Meal + "  with sour dough.")
elif (Bread == 3):
    print("You chose " + Meal + "  with rye toast.")
elif (Bread == 4):
    print("You chose " + Meal + "  with pancakes.")
else:
    print("We have eggs, but not that kind of bread.")

if ((MainChoice >= 1) or (MainChoice <= 3)):
    print("1. Syrup")
    print("2. Strawberries")
    print("3. Powdered Sugar")
Topping = int(input("Choose a topping: "))
if (Topping == 1):
    print ("You chose " + Meal + " with and syrup and Bread.")
elif (Topping == 2):
    print ("You chose " + Meal + " with and strawberries Bread.")
elif (Topping == 3):
    print ("You chose " + Meal + " with and powdered sugar Bread.")
else:
    print ("We have " + Meal + ", but not that topping Bread.")

if (MainChoice == 4):
    print("You chose oatmeal.")

else:
    print("Thank You for coming by and Eatting with us!")
```

**ERR MESSAGE** IF CHOSEN **OATMEAL** AND OTHER ITEMS:
AFTER SELECTION OF OATMEAL ITEM, WHEN SELECTION OF OTHER ITEMS, 
ERROR MESSAGE OCCUR

OUT VIA PYTHON

1. Eggs
2. Pancakes
3. Waffles
4. OatMeal
   Choose a breakfast item #: 4
   You've Choosen Oatmeal
5. Wheat Toast
6. Sour Dough
7. Rye Toast
8. White Bread
   Choose a type of bread: 1
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/(admin_name/Desktop/FOLDER/Breakfast-Menu.py", line 25, in 
   print("You chose " + Meal + "  with wheat toast.")
   NameError: name 'Meal' is not defined

**OUTPUT IF CHOSEN EVERYTHING # 1**

1. Eggs
2. Pancakes
3. Waffles
4. OatMeal
   Choose a breakfast item #: 1
   You've Choosen eggs
5. Wheat Toast
6. Sour Dough
7. Rye Toast
8. White Bread
   Choose a type of bread: 1
   You chose Eggs  with wheat toast.
9. Syrup
10. Strawberries
11. Powdered Sugar
    Choose a topping: 1
    You chose Eggs with and syrup and Bread.
    Thank You for coming by and Eatting with us!

Also How do I get the bread to show up with the selection of **Meal**, I understand the Meal value is the user input, after the 1 and 2nd selection, grabbing the third, how is the value of all 3 selections stored into **Meal** to output the selection at the end? If I'm asking this correctly.

Comment: You seem to have multiple questions here, and I'm not sure I understand what all of them are. But: (1) you need a `Meal = "Oatmeal"` under the first else, just like all those `Meal = "…"` statements under the other if/elif branches. (2) the value of all three selections _isn't_ stored into `Meal`; that's why you have to explicitly print `Meal + "…"`. If you want to store it into `Meal`, you have to do something like `Meal = Meal + " with wheat bread"`.

Comment: I understand the concept and will implement that into coding. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at what happens when `MainChoice` is 4 - only one of the conditional statements are executed, and in this case it's the `else` statement. None of the code under the `if` or `elif` statements gets executed, just the code under `else`. As such, there is no point in your program (when the input is 4) that the variable `Meal` is defined.

You need to add a definition of the `Meal` variable within the `else` statement for your code to work, so that when input is 4, Python actually has a value to use as the `Meal` variable.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. I wasn't sure to define Meal in the beginning or at the part your mentioning. I will do that then show the outcome.  Thanks Greatly for your input and Help.

Answer (score 0):

When you choose *OatMeal*, you didn't set anything for the *Meal* variable.

Unlike your 1, 2, 3 options where you set a Meal.

```
print("1. Eggs")
print("2. Pancakes")
print("3. Waffles")
print("4. OatMeal")
MainChoice = int(input("Choose a breakfast item #: "))
if(MainChoice == 1):
    Meal = "Eggs"  # Meal Set!
    print("You've Choosen eggs")
elif (MainChoice == 2):
    Meal = "Pancakes"  # Meal Set!
    print("You've Choosen pankcakes")
elif (MainChoice == 3):
    Meal = "Waffles"  # Meal Set!
    print("You've Choosen waffles")
else:
    # No Meal set :c
    print("You've Choosen Oatmeal")

if (MainChoice <= 4):
    print("1. Wheat Toast")
    print("2. Sour Dough")
    print("3. Rye Toast")
    print("4. White Bread")
Bread = int(input("Choose a type of bread: "))
elif (Bread == 1):
    print("You chose " + Meal + "  with wheat toast.")
elif (Bread == 2):
    print("You chose " + Meal + "  with sour dough.")
elif (Bread == 3):
    print("You chose " + Meal + "  with rye toast.")
elif (Bread == 4):
    print("You chose " + Meal + "  with pancakes.")
else:
    # No Meal called
    print("We have eggs, but not that kind of bread.")
```

Comment: Right I was looking at that as it was in the debugging state.  It will be added and ran to see the outcome. Will Update.

Answer (score 0):

Most persons have answered your direct question over why "Meal" is not defined, but I noticed some other things in the code. I'm going to make a few assumptions:

If no bread is selected, then no toppings for bread can be selected. In the options for toppings, you print that the topping is on a bread, but in the breads you allow for no bread to be selected.

If a bread is selected, when choosing the topping, the topping should be listed as being on the bread.

If oatmeal is selected, then you neither want bread, nor a topping. The 'if' statement before toppings will list the toppings no matter what (I think you want an 'and', not an 'or'). But regardless whether the toppings are displayed, the customer is asked to choose a topping. I believe this to a be a formatting issue.

In the statement, "We have eggs, but not that kind of bread.", I believe it should have been "We have " + Meal + ", but not that kind of bread.". I base this on the similar statement found after the toppings selection.

All this being said, I rewrote the code using an object oriented approach. This was not meant so much to answer your question, but to put out a different way of going about this.

```
UNDEFINED = "undefined"

class Selections:
    def __init__(self, statement, *args):
        self._items = args
        self._response = statement
        self._defaultResponse = UNDEFINED

    def setDefault(self, statement):
        self._defaultResponse = statement

    def makeSelection(self):
        for index, value in enumerate(self._items):
            print(str(index + 1) + ". " + value)
        selectedMeal = input("Please choose a breakfast item (by number): ") - 1
        if selectedMeal > len(self._items):
            if (self._defaultResponse != UNDEFINED):
                print(self._defaultResponse)
                self.last = UNDEFINED
                return
            selectedMeal = len(self._items) - 1
        self._printResponse(self._items[selectedMeal])
        self.last = self._items[selectedMeal]

    def _printResponse(self, item):
        print(self._response.format(item))

mainSelection = Selections("You've Choosen {}",
    "Eggs", "Pancakes", "Waffles", "OatMeal")

mainSelection.makeSelection()

if (mainSelection.last != "OatMeal"):
    breadSelection = Selections(
        "You chose " + mainSelection.last + " with {}.",
        "Wheat Toast", "Sour Dough", "Rye Toast", "White Bread")
    breadSelection.setDefault(
        "We have {}, but not that kind of bread".format(mainSelection.last))
    breadSelection.makeSelection()

    if (breadSelection.last != UNDEFINED):
        toppingSelection = Selections(
            "You chose " + mainSelection.last + " with {} on " + breadSelection.last, 
            "Syrup", "Strawberries", "Powdered Sugar")
        toppingSelection.setDefault(
            "We have {} and {}, but not that kind of topping".format(
                mainSelection.last, breadSelection.last))

        toppingSelection.makeSelection()
```